# Angular Comment Directive - Purpose / Intent / Best Practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Reading through, http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp I came across an example where a directive is called in a comment, specifically:

```
<!-- directive: w3-test-directive -->
```

You can see it work in http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_directive_comment

This seemed concerning to me. Can someone please describe the purpose or intent on when you'd desire something in a comment to be executed like this? At first glance it looks like bad design and perhaps something to avoid? If I'm wrong, I'd like to understand the intent/purpose and best practice of when to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from Angular's documentation

> Best Practice: Comment directives were commonly used in places where the DOM API limits the ability to create directives that spanned multiple elements (e.g. inside elements). AngularJS 1.2 introduces ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end as a better solution to this problem. **Developers are encouraged to use this over custom comment directives when possible**

However, it's best not to use them, as indicated here

> Best Practice: Prefer using directives via tag name and attributes over comment and class names. Doing so generally makes it easier to determine what directives a given element matches.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive